# Properties of this average over modular arithmetic unit subgroup: $G = \{ x \in (\Bbb{Z}/n)^{\times} : x^2 = 1 \pmod n\}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $G = \{ x \in \{0, \dots, n-1\} \subset \Bbb{Z} : x^2 =1  \pmod n\}$ which is isomorphic to a subgroup of $ (\Bbb{Z}/n)^{\times}$.  You perform the operation modulo $n$ and then lift back to the least residue in $G$.

Now define the sum:

$$
A_G = \dfrac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G} g
$$

Define $\Omega(n) = $ the total number of prime divisors of $n$ including multiplicties.  So $\Omega(40) = \Omega(2^3\cdot 5) = 4$.  Etc.

This is an element of $\Bbb{Q}$ in general.  When $n$ is squarefree and odd we know that $|G| = 2^{\Omega(n)}$ and when $n$ is squarefree and even we know that $|G| = 2^{\Omega(n) - 1}$.  Therefore that is well-understood.

**Proof.** Let $n = q_1 \cdots q_m$ be $n$'s prime factorization and $n$ square-free.  That means each $q_i$ is distinct and there are a total of $\Omega(n) = m$ of them. But $x \in G \iff x^2 = 1\pmod n \iff x^2=1$ modulo each $q_i$ by CRT.  Namely if $x^2 = 1 \pmod n$ then modulo that equation (which is possible beacuse $q_i \mid n)$ by $q_i$ to get $x^2 =1 \pmod q_i$.  And conversely if you have $x^2 = 1 \pmod {q_i}$ for each $i$ then by CRT isomorphism $\psi:\prod_i\Bbb{Z}/q_i \approx \Bbb{Z}/n$ we have that there exists an $x \in \{0, \dots, n-1\}$ such that $x^2 = 1 \pmod n$ and $x^2 = 1 \pmod {q_i}$.  Essentially there is a 1-1 correspondence between solutions in the product ring and solutions in $\Bbb{Z}/n$.  For each $q_i$ the only solutions modulo $q_i$ are from $x^2 - 1 = 0 \pmod {q_i}$ or $x = \pm 1 \pmod {q_i}$ necessarily since $q_i$ is a field.  Now multiply all the possibilities together to get the total count of solutions modulo $n$.  That would be $2^{\Omega(n)}$.  However modulo $q_i = 2$ or in the case that $2 \mid n$, we have that $\pm 1 = 1 \pmod {2}$ are the same number.  So we must subtract one possibility in that factor, making $2^{\Omega(n) - 1}$ whenever $2 \mid n$.  QED

Do we have an explicit formula for the average?

I know that:

$$
\sum_{g \in G} xg = S_G, \\
\forall x \in G
$$

because multiplication by an element $x \in G$ is a permutation of the group.

What I'm interested in are offsets in the ring.  If we similarly define $R = \{ 0, 1, \dots, n-1\}$ where multiplication is done in $\Bbb{Z}/n$ then lifted back to the least residue, then what is:

$$
\sum_{g \in G} (x + g)
$$

and how does it realte to $S_G$?

To be clear, the offset and $x\cdot g$ are done in $R, G$ respectively, but the $\sum$'s are done in $\Bbb{Z}$.

---

Okay, I partially-answered my question by providing an answer below.  The formula below can be written:

$$\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G} (g + x) = 
A_x({G_n}) :=\begin{cases} g - \dfrac{n\cdot\#(G_n \cap [n - g, n/2])}{|G_n|}, \text{ if } g \geq n/2 \\ \ \\ g + \dfrac{n\cdot\#(G_n \cap (g, n/2])}{|G_n|}, \text{ if } g \lt n/2 \end{cases} \\
$$

where $g := x_{(n)} =$ the unique element $g$ in $G$ such that $x = g \pmod n$.

But I am finding this formula not very nice to work with in practice.

So can you come up with a nicer formula, or asymptotic, given this as a baseline measurement of elegance?

---

Upon further reflection.

> **Main Question.**  Does this mean that $A_x(G_n)$, or the average over $G$ with modulo'd-in offset $x$ always falls within the bounds $[x_{(n)} - n/2,x_{(n)} + n/2]$?  This would be since $\#(G_n \cap (x_{(n)}, n/2])$ is maximally $\dfrac{|G_n|}{2}$ for example.

Comment: @Shaun thanks and hi :)

Comment: You're welcome! Hello! This is an interesting question (+1).

Comment: I know it's not elegant, but at some point in the formula, something's going to have to do the dirty job of lifting back into $\Bbb{Z}$, because that's where counting etc happen.

Comment: @Shaun I know it doesn't seem like it, but it has connections to twin primes.  In particular a simple counting formula I'm looking at.

Comment: @Shaun, I can by hand compute the average over $r^2 = 1 \pmod {15}$ or $G = \{1,4,11,14\}$ to be $2n = 30$, so the average value is $15/2 =n/2$ or $7.5$.

Comment: What's interesting about this group is that it only works for twin prime counting i.e. $x^2 = 1^2$ and not $x^2 = k^2$ for $k \gt 1$ (i.e. $4,6, \dots$-separated primes), because those don't necessarily form subgroups.  So the only time group comes into play in this route is with prime twins.

Comment: I am confused....what is $\Omega(n)$ in this context? $|G| \le n-1$. What am I missing.

Comment: @Mike $\Omega(n) = $ the total number of prime divisors of $n$ including multiplicities.  So $\Omega(40) = \Omega(8) + \Omega(5) = 3 + 1 = 4$.  When $n$ is squarefree, the total number of elements of $G_n$ is necessarily $2^{\Omega(n) - 1}$ when $n$ is even because the two doesn't contribute two possibilities under CRT argument, only one, because $-1 = 1 \pmod 2$ the same number.  When $q \gt 2$ you get two possibilities $\pm 1 \pmod q$ modulo that prime $q$.  Now CRT every thing up to get $2^{\Omega(n) - 1} = |G_n|$ when $2 \mid n$ and $2^{\Omega(n)}$ when $2 \nmid n$.

Comment: @DLeftAdjointtoU thank you for clarifying. But for the benefits of the site, I say you really need to put the elaboration in this comment into your OP. I am not sure if $\Omega(n)$ as used here is standard notation--in many branches of mathematics in fact, $\Omega(n)$ means something else altogether! [Note the 3 upvotes on my previous comment, indicating others probably found my question useful.]

Comment: @Mike Fixed per your requirements and also added in found formula below.  So I ask about the bounds now.  Clearly it's $x_{(n)} \pm n/2$, right?

Comment: @DLeftAdjointtoU in your OP you still need to define $\Omega(n)$ outright before you use it. This is really just the requirements of a good question, as you are using $\Omega(n)$ in a way that appears to not be standard.

Answer (score 0):

#### Pattern Evidence

Computing the "average" of this group does have a pattern, where $n \in \Bbb{N}$ is the domain of input, and not necessarily just square free:

```
from sympy import *

N = 1000

def square_roots_of_ksquared_modulo(d, k):
   roots = set()
   for x in range(0, d):
      if (x**2 - k**2) % d == 0:
         roots.add(x)
   return roots

def sum_of_roots_of1_modulo(n:int) -> int:
   G = square_roots_of_ksquared_modulo(n, 1)   
   S = 0
   
   for g in G:
      S += g
      
   return S / len(G)
   

for n in range(1, N):
   S = sum_of_roots_of1_modulo(n)
   
   print(n, S)
```

The average (without offset) seems to have an amazing, regular pattern:

```
1 0.0
2 1.0
3 1.5
4 2.0
5 2.5
6 3.0
7 3.5
8 4.0
9 4.5
10 5.0
11 5.5
12 6.0
13 6.5
14 7.0
15 7.5
16 8.0
17 8.5
18 9.0
19 9.5
20 10.0
21 10.5
22 11.0
23 11.5
24 12.0
25 12.5
26 13.0
27 13.5
28 14.0
29 14.5
30 15.0
31 15.5
32 16.0
33 16.5
34 17.0
35 17.5
36 18.0
37 18.5
38 19.0
39 19.5
40 20.0
41 20.5
42 21.0
43 21.5
44 22.0
45 22.5
46 23.0
47 23.5
48 24.0
49 24.5
50 25.0
51 25.5
52 26.0
53 26.5
54 27.0
55 27.5
56 28.0
57 28.5
58 29.0
59 29.5
60 30.0
61 30.5
62 31.0
63 31.5
64 32.0
65 32.5
66 33.0
67 33.5
68 34.0
69 34.5
70 35.0
71 35.5
72 36.0
73 36.5
74 37.0
75 37.5
76 38.0
77 38.5
78 39.0
79 39.5
80 40.0
81 40.5
82 41.0
83 41.5
84 42.0
85 42.5
86 43.0
87 43.5
88 44.0
89 44.5
90 45.0
91 45.5
92 46.0
93 46.5
94 47.0
95 47.5
96 48.0
97 48.5
98 49.0
99 49.5
100 50.0
101 50.5
102 51.0
103 51.5
104 52.0
105 52.5
106 53.0
107 53.5
108 54.0
109 54.5
110 55.0
111 55.5
112 56.0
113 56.5
114 57.0
115 57.5
116 58.0
117 58.5
118 59.0
119 59.5
120 60.0
121 60.5
122 61.0
123 61.5
124 62.0
125 62.5
126 63.0
127 63.5
128 64.0
129 64.5
130 65.0
131 65.5
132 66.0
133 66.5
134 67.0
135 67.5
136 68.0
137 68.5
138 69.0
139 69.5
140 70.0
141 70.5
142 71.0
143 71.5
144 72.0
145 72.5
146 73.0
147 73.5
148 74.0
149 74.5
150 75.0
151 75.5
152 76.0
153 76.5
154 77.0
155 77.5
156 78.0
157 78.5
158 79.0
159 79.5
160 80.0
161 80.5
162 81.0
163 81.5
164 82.0
165 82.5
166 83.0
167 83.5
168 84.0
169 84.5
170 85.0
171 85.5
172 86.0
173 86.5
174 87.0
175 87.5
176 88.0
177 88.5
178 89.0
179 89.5
180 90.0
181 90.5
182 91.0
183 91.5
184 92.0
185 92.5
186 93.0
187 93.5
188 94.0
189 94.5
190 95.0
191 95.5
192 96.0
193 96.5
194 97.0
195 97.5
196 98.0
197 98.5
198 99.0
199 99.5
200 100.0
201 100.5
202 101.0
203 101.5
204 102.0
205 102.5
206 103.0
207 103.5
208 104.0
209 104.5
210 105.0
211 105.5
212 106.0
213 106.5
214 107.0
215 107.5
216 108.0
217 108.5
218 109.0
219 109.5
220 110.0
221 110.5
222 111.0
223 111.5
224 112.0
225 112.5
226 113.0
227 113.5
228 114.0
229 114.5
230 115.0
231 115.5
232 116.0
233 116.5
234 117.0
235 117.5
236 118.0
237 118.5
238 119.0
239 119.5
240 120.0
241 120.5
242 121.0
243 121.5
244 122.0
245 122.5
246 123.0
247 123.5
248 124.0
249 124.5
250 125.0
251 125.5
252 126.0
253 126.5
254 127.0
255 127.5
256 128.0
257 128.5
258 129.0
259 129.5
260 130.0
261 130.5
262 131.0
263 131.5
264 132.0
265 132.5
266 133.0
267 133.5
268 134.0
269 134.5
270 135.0
271 135.5
272 136.0
273 136.5
274 137.0
275 137.5
276 138.0
277 138.5
278 139.0
279 139.5
280 140.0
281 140.5
282 141.0
283 141.5
284 142.0
285 142.5
286 143.0
287 143.5
288 144.0
289 144.5
290 145.0
291 145.5
292 146.0
293 146.5
294 147.0
295 147.5
296 148.0
297 148.5
298 149.0
299 149.5
300 150.0
301 150.5
302 151.0
303 151.5
304 152.0
305 152.5
306 153.0
307 153.5
308 154.0
309 154.5
310 155.0
311 155.5
312 156.0
313 156.5
314 157.0
315 157.5
316 158.0
317 158.5
318 159.0
319 159.5
320 160.0
321 160.5
322 161.0
323 161.5
324 162.0
325 162.5
326 163.0
327 163.5
328 164.0
329 164.5
330 165.0
331 165.5
332 166.0
333 166.5
334 167.0
335 167.5
336 168.0
337 168.5
338 169.0
339 169.5
340 170.0
341 170.5
342 171.0
343 171.5
344 172.0
345 172.5
346 173.0
347 173.5
348 174.0
349 174.5
350 175.0
351 175.5
352 176.0
353 176.5
354 177.0
355 177.5
356 178.0
357 178.5
358 179.0
359 179.5
360 180.0
361 180.5
362 181.0
363 181.5
364 182.0
365 182.5
366 183.0
367 183.5
368 184.0
369 184.5
370 185.0
371 185.5
372 186.0
373 186.5
374 187.0
375 187.5
376 188.0
377 188.5
378 189.0
379 189.5
380 190.0
381 190.5
382 191.0
383 191.5
384 192.0
385 192.5
386 193.0
387 193.5
388 194.0
389 194.5
390 195.0
391 195.5
392 196.0
393 196.5
394 197.0
395 197.5
396 198.0
397 198.5
398 199.0
399 199.5
400 200.0
401 200.5
402 201.0
403 201.5
404 202.0
405 202.5
406 203.0
407 203.5
408 204.0
409 204.5
410 205.0
411 205.5
412 206.0
413 206.5
414 207.0
415 207.5
416 208.0
417 208.5
418 209.0
419 209.5
420 210.0
421 210.5
422 211.0
423 211.5
424 212.0
425 212.5
426 213.0
427 213.5
428 214.0
429 214.5
430 215.0
431 215.5
432 216.0
433 216.5
434 217.0
435 217.5
436 218.0
437 218.5
438 219.0
439 219.5
440 220.0
441 220.5
442 221.0
443 221.5
444 222.0
445 222.5
446 223.0
447 223.5
448 224.0
449 224.5
450 225.0
451 225.5
452 226.0
453 226.5
454 227.0
455 227.5
456 228.0
457 228.5
458 229.0
459 229.5
460 230.0
461 230.5
462 231.0
463 231.5
464 232.0
465 232.5
466 233.0
467 233.5
468 234.0
469 234.5
470 235.0
471 235.5
472 236.0
473 236.5
474 237.0
475 237.5
476 238.0
477 238.5
478 239.0
479 239.5
480 240.0
481 240.5
482 241.0
483 241.5
484 242.0
485 242.5
486 243.0
487 243.5
488 244.0
489 244.5
490 245.0
491 245.5
492 246.0
493 246.5
494 247.0
495 247.5
496 248.0
497 248.5
498 249.0
499 249.5
500 250.0
501 250.5
502 251.0
503 251.5
504 252.0
505 252.5
506 253.0
507 253.5
508 254.0
509 254.5
510 255.0
511 255.5
512 256.0
513 256.5
514 257.0
515 257.5
516 258.0
517 258.5
518 259.0
519 259.5
520 260.0
521 260.5
522 261.0
523 261.5
524 262.0
525 262.5
526 263.0
527 263.5
528 264.0
529 264.5
530 265.0
531 265.5
532 266.0
533 266.5
534 267.0
535 267.5
536 268.0
537 268.5
538 269.0
539 269.5
540 270.0
541 270.5
542 271.0
543 271.5
544 272.0
545 272.5
546 273.0
547 273.5
548 274.0
549 274.5
550 275.0
551 275.5
552 276.0
553 276.5
554 277.0
555 277.5
556 278.0
557 278.5
558 279.0
559 279.5
560 280.0
561 280.5
562 281.0
563 281.5
564 282.0
565 282.5
566 283.0
567 283.5
568 284.0
569 284.5
570 285.0
571 285.5
572 286.0
573 286.5
574 287.0
575 287.5
576 288.0
577 288.5
578 289.0
579 289.5
580 290.0
581 290.5
582 291.0
583 291.5
584 292.0
585 292.5
586 293.0
587 293.5
588 294.0
589 294.5
590 295.0
591 295.5
592 296.0
593 296.5
594 297.0
595 297.5
596 298.0
597 298.5
598 299.0
599 299.5
600 300.0
601 300.5
602 301.0
603 301.5
604 302.0
605 302.5
606 303.0
607 303.5
608 304.0
609 304.5
610 305.0
611 305.5
612 306.0
613 306.5
614 307.0
615 307.5
616 308.0
617 308.5
618 309.0
619 309.5
620 310.0
621 310.5
622 311.0
623 311.5
624 312.0
625 312.5
626 313.0
627 313.5
628 314.0
629 314.5
630 315.0
631 315.5
632 316.0
633 316.5
634 317.0
635 317.5
636 318.0
637 318.5
638 319.0
639 319.5
640 320.0
641 320.5
642 321.0
643 321.5
644 322.0
645 322.5
646 323.0
647 323.5
648 324.0
649 324.5
650 325.0
651 325.5
652 326.0
653 326.5
654 327.0
655 327.5
656 328.0
657 328.5
658 329.0
659 329.5
660 330.0
661 330.5
662 331.0
663 331.5
664 332.0
665 332.5
666 333.0
667 333.5
668 334.0
669 334.5
670 335.0
671 335.5
672 336.0
673 336.5
674 337.0
675 337.5
676 338.0
677 338.5
678 339.0
679 339.5
680 340.0
681 340.5
682 341.0
683 341.5
684 342.0
685 342.5
686 343.0
687 343.5
688 344.0
689 344.5
690 345.0
691 345.5
692 346.0
693 346.5
694 347.0
695 347.5
696 348.0
697 348.5
698 349.0
699 349.5
700 350.0
701 350.5
702 351.0
703 351.5
704 352.0
705 352.5
706 353.0
707 353.5
708 354.0
709 354.5
710 355.0
711 355.5
712 356.0
713 356.5
714 357.0
715 357.5
716 358.0
717 358.5
718 359.0
719 359.5
720 360.0
721 360.5
722 361.0
723 361.5
724 362.0
725 362.5
726 363.0
727 363.5
728 364.0
729 364.5
730 365.0
731 365.5
732 366.0
733 366.5
734 367.0
735 367.5
736 368.0
737 368.5
738 369.0
739 369.5
740 370.0
741 370.5
742 371.0
743 371.5
744 372.0
745 372.5
746 373.0
747 373.5
748 374.0
749 374.5
750 375.0
751 375.5
752 376.0
753 376.5
754 377.0
755 377.5
756 378.0
757 378.5
758 379.0
759 379.5
760 380.0
761 380.5
762 381.0
763 381.5
764 382.0
765 382.5
766 383.0
767 383.5
768 384.0
769 384.5
770 385.0
771 385.5
772 386.0
773 386.5
774 387.0
775 387.5
776 388.0
777 388.5
778 389.0
779 389.5
780 390.0
781 390.5
782 391.0
783 391.5
784 392.0
785 392.5
786 393.0
787 393.5
788 394.0
789 394.5
790 395.0
791 395.5
792 396.0
793 396.5
794 397.0
795 397.5
796 398.0
797 398.5
798 399.0
799 399.5
800 400.0
801 400.5
802 401.0
803 401.5
804 402.0
805 402.5
806 403.0
807 403.5
808 404.0
809 404.5
810 405.0
811 405.5
812 406.0
813 406.5
814 407.0
815 407.5
816 408.0
817 408.5
818 409.0
819 409.5
820 410.0
821 410.5
822 411.0
823 411.5
824 412.0
825 412.5
826 413.0
827 413.5
828 414.0
829 414.5
830 415.0
831 415.5
832 416.0
833 416.5
834 417.0
835 417.5
836 418.0
837 418.5
838 419.0
839 419.5
840 420.0
841 420.5
842 421.0
843 421.5
844 422.0
845 422.5
846 423.0
847 423.5
848 424.0
849 424.5
850 425.0
851 425.5
852 426.0
853 426.5
854 427.0
855 427.5
856 428.0
857 428.5
858 429.0
859 429.5
860 430.0
861 430.5
862 431.0
863 431.5
864 432.0
865 432.5
866 433.0
867 433.5
868 434.0
869 434.5
870 435.0
871 435.5
872 436.0
873 436.5
874 437.0
875 437.5
876 438.0
877 438.5
878 439.0
879 439.5
880 440.0
881 440.5
882 441.0
883 441.5
884 442.0
885 442.5
886 443.0
887 443.5
888 444.0
889 444.5
890 445.0
891 445.5
892 446.0
893 446.5
894 447.0
895 447.5
896 448.0
897 448.5
898 449.0
899 449.5
900 450.0
901 450.5
902 451.0
903 451.5
904 452.0
905 452.5
906 453.0
907 453.5
908 454.0
909 454.5
910 455.0
911 455.5
912 456.0
913 456.5
914 457.0
915 457.5
916 458.0
917 458.5
918 459.0
919 459.5
920 460.0
921 460.5
922 461.0
923 461.5
924 462.0
925 462.5
926 463.0
927 463.5
928 464.0
929 464.5
930 465.0
931 465.5
932 466.0
933 466.5
934 467.0
935 467.5
936 468.0
937 468.5
938 469.0
939 469.5
940 470.0
941 470.5
942 471.0
943 471.5
944 472.0
945 472.5
946 473.0
947 473.5
948 474.0
949 474.5
950 475.0
951 475.5
952 476.0
953 476.5
954 477.0
955 477.5
956 478.0
957 478.5
958 479.0
959 479.5
960 480.0
961 480.5
962 481.0
963 481.5
964 482.0
965 482.5
966 483.0
967 483.5
968 484.0
969 484.5
970 485.0
971 485.5
972 486.0
973 486.5
974 487.0
975 487.5
976 488.0
977 488.5
978 489.0
979 489.5
980 490.0
981 490.5
982 491.0
983 491.5
984 492.0
985 492.5
986 493.0
987 493.5
988 494.0
989 494.5
990 495.0
991 495.5
992 496.0
993 496.5
994 497.0
995 497.5
996 498.0
997 498.5
998 499.0
999 499.5
```

Thus, $f(1) = 0$ an for $n \geq 2$, $f(n) := \sum_{g \in G_n} \dfrac{g}{|G_n|} = \dfrac{n}{2}$.   This post is just about the evidence.  Not a proof of this apparent fact.

Comment: I also see now why it has to be true.  It's because you can pair up $r^2 = 1 \pmod n$ with $-r$, and they occur symmetrically across $n/2$ on the number line.  If there is one _at $r = n/2$_ then it would only help it become more averaged at that halfway point.

Answer (score 0):

#### Sketch of formula proof.

Let's write $x_{(n)}$ to mean $x_{(n)} \in \Bbb{Z}$ but $x = x_{(n)} \pmod n$ and $x_{(n)}$ is the minimal such non-negative integer.  We can assume that $r \leq n/2$.

There are a few cases, where $x':= x_{(n)}$ can occur relative to $r$ and $n/2$:

$$
1 \leq r \leq n/2 \leq n-r \leq \textbf{x}' \lt n \textbf{ (Case 0)} \\
1 \leq r \leq n/2 \leq \textbf{x}' \lt n - r \lt n \textbf{ (Case 1)} \\
1 \leq r \leq \textbf{x}' \lt n/2\leq n-r \lt n \textbf{ (Case 2)}\\
1 \leq \textbf{x}' \lt r \leq n/2 \leq n-r\lt n \textbf{ (Case 3)}\\
$$

In Case 0, we clearly have $(x' - r)_{(n)} = x' - r$ and $(x' + r)_{(n)} = x' + r - n$.  So we have $2x' - n$ in case $0$.  In Case 1 we have both $(x' - r)_{(n)} = x' - r$ and $(x' + r)_{(n)} = x' + r$.  So in that case we get $2x'$.

In Case 2 we have $(x' - r)_{(n)} = x' - r$ and $(x' + r)_{(n)} = x' + r$ as well so $2x'$ in that case. Finally in case $3$ we have, $(x' + r)_{(n)} = x' + r $, but $x' - r \lt 0$ so that $(x' - r)_{(n)} = x' - r + n$, and what you end up with is $2x' + n$.

---

In the averaging problem we have:

$$
A({G_n}) :=\begin{cases} x' - \frac{n\cdot\#\{g \in G : g \leq n/2, g + x' \geq n\}}{|G_n|}, \text{ if } x' \geq n/2 \\ \ \\ x' + \frac{n\cdot\#\{g \in G : g \leq n/2, x' \lt g\}}{|G_n|}, \text{ if } x' \lt n/2 \end{cases}
$$

---

#### Verification code.

Though this formula may seem legit, the code doesn't check out:

```
from sympy import *
from functools import reduce

N = 100
k = 1

def square_roots_of_ksquared_modulo(d, k):
   roots = set()
   for x in range(0, d):
      if (x**2 - k**2) % d == 0:
         roots.add(x)
   return roots

def average_sqrt1_modulo(n, x:int):
   # x = internal offset
   S = 0
   
   roots= square_roots_of_ksquared_modulo(n, k=1)
   
   for r in roots:
      S += (x - r) % n
      
   return S / len(roots)

def formula_for_avg_sqrt1_modulo(n, x:int):
   S = x % n
   
   roots = square_roots_of_ksquared_modulo(n, k=1)
   
   if x >= n/2:
      for r in roots:
         if n - (x%n) <= r <= n/2:
            S -= n/len(roots)
   else:
      for r in roots:
         if (x%n) < r <= n/2:
            S += n/len(roots)
   
   return S
   
for n in range(1, N):      
   for x in range(0, n):
      f = formula_for_avg_sqrt1_modulo(n, x)
      a = average_sqrt1_modulo(n, x)
      
      diff = f - a
      
      print(f'n,x,actual, diff={n},{x},{a}, {diff}')
```

**Outputs.**

```
n,x,actual, diff=1,0,0.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=2,0,1.0, 1.0
n,x,actual, diff=2,1,0.0, -1.0
n,x,actual, diff=3,0,1.5, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=3,1,1.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=3,2,0.5, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=4,0,2.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=4,1,1.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=4,2,2.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=4,3,1.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=5,0,2.5, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=5,1,1.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=5,2,2.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=5,3,3.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=5,4,1.5, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=6,0,3.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=6,1,1.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=6,2,2.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=6,3,3.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=6,4,4.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=6,5,2.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=7,0,3.5, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=7,1,1.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=7,2,2.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=7,3,3.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=7,4,4.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=7,5,5.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=7,6,2.5, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=8,0,4.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=8,1,3.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=8,2,4.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=8,3,3.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=8,4,4.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=8,5,3.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=8,6,4.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=8,7,3.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=9,0,4.5, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=9,1,1.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=9,2,2.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=9,3,3.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=9,4,4.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=9,5,5.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=9,6,6.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=9,7,7.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=9,8,3.5, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=10,0,5.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=10,1,1.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=10,2,2.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=10,3,3.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=10,4,4.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=10,5,5.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=10,6,6.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=10,7,7.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=10,8,8.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=10,9,4.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=11,0,5.5, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=11,1,1.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=11,2,2.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=11,3,3.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=11,4,4.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=11,5,5.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=11,6,6.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=11,7,7.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=11,8,8.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=11,9,9.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=11,10,4.5, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=12,0,6.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=12,1,4.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=12,2,5.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=12,3,6.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=12,4,7.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=12,5,5.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=12,6,6.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=12,7,4.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=12,8,5.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=12,9,6.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=12,10,7.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=12,11,5.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=13,0,6.5, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=13,1,1.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=13,2,2.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=13,3,3.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=13,4,4.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=13,5,5.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=13,6,6.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=13,7,7.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=13,8,8.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=13,9,9.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=13,10,10.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=13,11,11.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=13,12,5.5, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=14,0,7.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=14,1,1.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=14,2,2.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=14,3,3.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=14,4,4.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=14,5,5.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=14,6,6.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=14,7,7.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=14,8,8.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=14,9,9.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=14,10,10.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=14,11,11.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=14,12,12.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=14,13,6.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=15,0,7.5, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=15,1,4.75, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=15,2,5.75, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=15,3,6.75, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=15,4,4.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=15,5,5.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=15,6,6.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=15,7,7.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=15,8,8.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=15,9,9.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=15,10,10.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=15,11,7.25, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=15,12,8.25, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=15,13,9.25, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=15,14,6.5, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=16,0,8.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=16,1,5.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=16,2,6.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=16,3,7.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=16,4,8.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=16,5,9.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=16,6,10.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=16,7,7.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=16,8,8.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=16,9,5.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=16,10,6.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=16,11,7.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=16,12,8.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=16,13,9.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=16,14,10.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=16,15,7.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=17,0,8.5, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=17,1,1.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=17,2,2.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=17,3,3.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=17,4,4.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=17,5,5.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=17,6,6.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=17,7,7.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=17,8,8.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=17,9,9.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=17,10,10.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=17,11,11.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=17,12,12.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=17,13,13.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=17,14,14.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=17,15,15.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=17,16,7.5, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=18,0,9.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=18,1,1.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=18,2,2.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=18,3,3.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=18,4,4.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=18,5,5.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=18,6,6.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=18,7,7.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=18,8,8.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=18,9,9.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=18,10,10.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=18,11,11.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=18,12,12.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=18,13,13.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=18,14,14.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=18,15,15.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=18,16,16.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=18,17,8.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=19,0,9.5, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=19,1,1.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=19,2,2.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=19,3,3.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=19,4,4.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=19,5,5.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=19,6,6.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=19,7,7.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=19,8,8.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=19,9,9.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=19,10,10.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=19,11,11.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=19,12,12.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=19,13,13.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=19,14,14.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=19,15,15.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=19,16,16.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=19,17,17.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=19,18,8.5, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=20,0,10.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=20,1,6.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=20,2,7.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=20,3,8.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=20,4,9.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=20,5,10.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=20,6,11.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=20,7,12.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=20,8,13.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=20,9,9.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=20,10,10.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=20,11,6.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=20,12,7.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=20,13,8.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=20,14,9.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=20,15,10.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=20,16,11.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=20,17,12.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=20,18,13.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=20,19,9.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=21,0,10.5, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=21,1,6.25, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=21,2,7.25, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=21,3,8.25, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=21,4,9.25, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=21,5,10.25, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=21,6,11.25, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=21,7,12.25, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=21,8,8.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=21,9,9.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=21,10,10.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=21,11,11.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=21,12,12.0, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=21,13,7.75, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=21,14,8.75, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=21,15,9.75, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=21,16,10.75, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=21,17,11.75, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=21,18,12.75, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=21,19,13.75, 0.0
n,x,actual, diff=21,20,9.5, 0.0
```

So this formula is valid for $n \gt 2$.  For $n = 1,2$ of course those are easy-to-handle simpler cases.

Comment: The reason you add $(x - r)_{(n)} + (x + r)_{(n)}$ is because for $n \gt 2$ the square roots of unity $r, -r$ can be paired together.